# How can I use the "rabbitmqctl set_permissions" command to allow a RabbitMQ user to only subscribe to MQTT topics, but not publish?

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt, rabbitmqctl, rabbitmq-management

I am using RabbitMQ MQTT and I would like only to allow one user to publish to topics, and all other users to only subscribe. I understand that running `rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p 'vhost' 'username' '.*' '.*' '.*'` will give the user permission to do anything on the vhost. How do I use the `rabbitmqctl set_permissions` to allow the user to only subscribe to MQTT topics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rabbitmqctl set_permissions` structure is:

```bash
rabbitmqctl set_permissions [-p <vhostpath>] <user> <configure> <write> <read>
```

So following your request, you would use the `set_permissions` command with blank regular expressions for configure and write permissions and .* for read permissions, like:

```bash
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p your_vhost your_user "" "" ".*"
```

UPD:
Subscribing to a topic results in the MQTT plugin creating a queue and a binding, which requires configure and write permissions in that case, so you can limit access to certain queues and exchange patterns kinda like this:

```bash
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p your_vhost your_user "^mqtt-subscription-.*$" "^mqtt-subscription-.*$" ".*"
```

allowing the user to configure and write only to the specific queues that the MQTT plugin would create and read from all queues

Comment: With those permissions the client is failing to subscribe to any topic. I am seeing this error in the RabbitMQ log `MQTT resource access refused: configure access to queue 'mqtt-subscription-client-idqos0' in vhost '/' refused for user 'consumer'`. Seems like the configure  permission is required for subscription. Even the write permission to some extent, because if I set both configure and read to `.*`,  the subscription fails with the error `Failed to add binding between exchange 'amq.topic' in vhost '/' and queue 'mqtt-subscription-client-idqos0'`

Comment: I bet subscribing to a topic results in the MQTT plugin creating a queue and a binding, which requires configure and write permissions in that case, so you can limit access to certain queue and exchange patterns kinda like this:
`rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p your_vhost your_user "^mqtt-subscription-.*$" "^mqtt-subscription-.*$" ".*"`
allowing the user to configure and write only to the specific queues that the MQTT plugin would create and read from all queues

Comment: That works thank you. Please edit your answer so that I can mark it as the accepted one.